# Use WireGuard for combining bandwidth (multiwan)

Tags: vpn, wide-area-network, openwrt, wireguard

Is it possible to combine multiple uplinks for getting faster VPN access to a server with WireGuard?

I already played around with MultiWAN (mwan3, OpenWRT) in the past but for VPN access, its only possible to use a single connection (OpenVPN, ...)

Maybe its possible with WireGuard to get 60MBit between Laptop and Server like in the attached example?

[multiwan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrzfN.png)

Comment: a multiwan connection must be supported on both sides as i remeber on the time i alwas a trainee...

Comment: wireguard uses cryptorouting: 1 IP(:port) <=> 1 key <=> 1 peer. If the same key is seen from an other IP then that means the peer is roaming: you cannot load balance. You could have your laptop use 3 wireguard interfaces to have 3 connections to the server, but then that would be nothing different than any other solution. In short wireguard won't help alone here. MPTCP v1 was included in vanilla kernel 5.6, you could take a look at this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8684